# Starting/removing/upgrading transmission-daemon wont work

Tags: server, transmission

When I type `sudo apt-get upgrade` the following is output:

```
Setting up transmission-daemon (2.84-0ubuntu0.14.10.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript transmission-daemon, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package transmission-daemon (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 transmission-daemon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also when I type the following: `sudo service transmission-daemon stop` this is the output:

```
+ sudo service transmission-daemon stop
stop: Unknown instance:
```

What is wrong? I am an ubuntu beginner.

Answer (score 0):

open /etc/default/transmission-daemon with a editor with root permissions like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/transmission-daemon
```

then change the

```
ENABLE_DAEMON=0
```

to

```
ENABLE_DAEMON=1
```

for nano do the ctrl+o to save and ctrl+x to exit.
then that package should be upgradeable.

if that helps mark yourself affected to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/transmission/+bug/1058518

Comment: There is no such file on my server. When I search for the file I get the following result: http://oi58.tinypic.com/2lthuts.jpg